# Grapher COM Connection to C#

Tags: c#, com

I've been trying to automate Golden Software's Grapher (version 15) using C#. The program's guide for C++ (the file looks old, however, and I am not sure if it applies in a similar way now) notes that the user should:

> 1. Create a new AppWizard dialog-based application, using all the standard options.
> 2. Edit the main dialog resource to contain the desired UI.  In this example, a Run and Close button.
> 3. Use Class Wizard to add a handler for the "Run" button.
> 4. Start Class Wizard, choose Add Class..., From a Type Library...
> 5. Grapher's type library is contained within the grapher.tlb file, so select    this file.  Rename the classes, in order, Document, Worksheet, Application, Documents.    Add all classes.

To me, this meant that I tried to use ([after some other reading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/aa645736%28v=vs.94%29?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) the `tlbimp` command in developer prompt which I used to translate the "grapher.tlb" file into "GrapherTypeLib.dll". I further used `regasm` to register this file (as [some places](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/tzat5yw6(v=vs.94)) seemed to suggest this is necessary).

I added the reference to GrapherTypeLib.dll to my C# project along with making it not embed and to have a local copy.

However, with my code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;

using GrapherTypeLib;

public class Grapher15
    {
        public Grapher15(Functions _function, string _data, DataTable _summary, IProgress<int> progress)
        {
            try
            {
                CreateProfiles(_data);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        private void CreateProfiles(string _data)
        {
            // Create an instance which can work in the background
            IAppObject _instance = new ApplicationClass();
            _instance.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

I always crash out trying to create the application. I should note that I have tried different options here, including `new Application()`, which result in the same thing:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {41F3A3D2-EAF3-42F0-9F62-A6E55F08F7E7} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).'

Based on my above checks and regasm, I would have thought that everything is registered properly. I should note that when this first started, I also re-installed the program to make sure all of the registrations were done properly. However, I then decided to check regedit and that doesn't actually seem to have the one CLSID this is looking for:

[image]

I started investigating and using ildasm, I found out that this GUID matches what should be the registry value for `GrapherTypeLib.ApplicationClass` which does not seem to be registered in the regid listing. At the same time, ildasm notes, for example, a different value to `GrapherTypeLib.Application` than what is in the above regid list.

So, for a short conclusion -- **does anyone have any idea what is going wrong in the above?**

Comment: It looks like a x86/x64 issue. The screenshot shows you registered for x64, but your exe is possibly running as x86 .

Comment: Thanks @SimonMourier. I didn't actually mention above as I'd forgot, but I've tried assembling the solution both as x64 and x86 and both crash with the same error. Grapher itself was installed as a 64-bit application if that should make a difference.

Comment: REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG on {41F3A3D2-EAF3-42F0-9F62-A6E55F08F7E7} means a registry key {41F3A3D2-EAF3-42F0-9F62-A6E55F08F7E7} is missing where COM looks. To make sure where COM looks, use a tool such as procmon from sysinternals (filter on your .exe and on registry accesses)